# How to do user interaction on commands in Chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have some commands which need user interaction so that time either I want to `Enter` with defaults or feed some input from chef itself so my instance won't fail at run time. For example...

```
./build-ca        # The command I am executing
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [IN]: 
State or Province Name (full name) [KA]:
```

Here pressing `enter` will does the job (uses defaults) while doint it manually, but how I can automate this thing using Chef, some times I need to press `y` or other values as well. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can your command accept parameters?

Comment: Render your `openssl.cnf` using a [template](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html) and then call the `openssl` executable with `-config openssl.cnf`.

Comment: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ssl_certificate

Answer (score 1):

If you have no alternatives (e.g. passing arguments or an input file to the command or script, as already suggested by others) you can script the interactions with `expect` and run it from your chef recipe using the `bash` resource.

See [How to automate user interactive command in chef recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203989/how-to-automate-user-interactive-command-in-chef-recipe)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the [Easy RSA](https://openvpn.net/easyrsa.html) scripts to generate OpenVPN certificates.

One solution would be to generate the `./vars` file and call `pkitool` ([which is called by the old `build-ca` script](https://github.com/OpenVPN/easy-rsa-old/blob/master/easy-rsa/2.0/build-ca)):

```ruby
easy_rsa_path = '/usr/share/easy-rsa' # or whatever

template "#{easy_rsa_path}/vars" # [...]

bash 'build-ca' do
  cwd easy_rsa_path
  code <<-EOH
    source ./vars && \
    ./clean-all && \
    ./pkitool --batch --initca
  EOH
  creates "#{easy_rsa_path}/keys/ca.crt"
end
```

A better approach would be to use OpenSSL to generate the certificate. You can see an implementation example in the [`openvpn` cookbook](https://github.com/xhost-cookbooks/openvpn/blob/v2.1.0/recipes/default.rb#L98-L108):

```ruby
bash 'openvpn-initca' do
  environment('KEY_CN' => "#{node['openvpn']['key']['org']} CA")
  code <<-EOF
    openssl req -batch -days #{node["openvpn"]["key"]["ca_expire"]} \
      -nodes -new -newkey rsa:#{key_size} -sha1 -x509 \
      -keyout #{node["openvpn"]["signing_ca_key"]} \
      -out #{node["openvpn"]["signing_ca_cert"]} \
      -config #{key_dir}/openssl.cnf
  EOF
  not_if { ::File.exists?(node['openvpn']['signing_ca_cert']) }
end
```